# Output not displaying correctly on HDMI connection to display

Tags: graphics-card, display, hdmi

My Asus AT3N7A-I-based computer is connected to my TV via a HDMI cable. However the screen is cut off by 1cm in each direction. I have so far been unable to find settings to change or resize the display. It has an onbuilt nVidia grapics adaptor and is a 32" Bush TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting in NVidia and ATI settings for overscanning, over cropping, or something similar to that. If you change this, it will utilize the entire screen.